# Query to get index of member in multiple classes?

Tags: sql

Given the following table `Attendance`, where `AttID` is the primary key and table is sorted. I'm attempting to search in the index of `MemberID` in each `ClassID`, or return total members in a class if the `MemberID` does not exist in the class (this condition is less important to me).

| AttID | ClassID | MemberID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 30 |
| 5 | 2 | 40 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 50 |

For example:

1. Given the target `MemberID` is `1`, I will get the following

| ClassID | Index |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |

2. Given the target `MemberID` is `2`, I will get the following

| ClassID | Index |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |

I'm using these results to determine whether a member that attended a class is within the classes' capacity.

Answer (score 0):

"5" is repeated for `Attid` so it is not a primary key.  I will assume this is a typo.

You have basically described the `row_number()` function:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by classid order by attid) as seqnum
      from attendance a
     ) a
where memberid = ?
```